# problem connecting to VM with xfreerdp: how to solve

Tags: 16.04, rdp

I'm trying to connect to VM with `xfreerdp` (using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS). I have installed the latest version of the `xfreerdp` via Remmina PPA, my current version of FreeRDP is `2.0.0-rc1`.

However, whenever I'm trying to execute the script to connect to VM, I get the following message:

```
[23:17:51:762] [9590:9591] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - certificate not trusted, aborting.
[23:17:51:763] [9590:9591] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_CANCELLED [0x0002000B]
[23:17:51:763] [9590:9591] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
[23:17:51:763] [9590:9591] [ERROR][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Freerdp connect error exit status 1
```

The script seems to work correctly on my friend's laptop (he's using another Linux distribution, though).

Do you have any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: What kind of VM?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem connecting from a linux host to Windows 7 remote desktop. You need to delete the entry for this server from the freerdp known_hosts file. In my case, Kubuntu 18.04, the file was located here `~/.config/freerdp`.